# NI Stack shows different outputs on Kinect

Tags: calibration, kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So basically, if I build the sample source files such as NiSimpleViewer.cpp I see a clear disparity between depth and image data when I use *DISPLAY_MODE_OVERLAY* but when I run the binary *Sample-NiSimpleViewer* provided with the library I get a good overlap between the data

Am I missing something, do I have to calibrate my kinect manually and use those parameters? or if you have a link to the source on which the binary *ni/ni/openni/bin/Sample-NiSimpleViewer* is built on, please reply me. Thank you.

I initially assumed that the binaries provided in the stack *ni* @ *ni/ni/openni/bin* are actually built on code provided @ n*i/ni/openni/build/openni/Samples* but when I run *ni/ni/openni/bin/Sample-NiSimpleViewer* it gives a different output than *ni/ni/openni/build/openni/Samples/NiSimpleViewer/NiSimpleViewer.cpp*

Here are the images that I obtained from both
[image: Binary provided with NI stack]
[image: image description]

If you look at my hand in both the images then you can see a clear disparity.

[I am using diamondback on Ubuntu 10.04]

Best,
CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9328/ni-stack-shows-different-outputs-on-kinect/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems, that the registration is not turned on in the second example (bottom image). Just look in the example ho to turn on/off registration.

---

Originally posted by [Suat Gedikli](https://answers.ros.org/users/275/suat-gedikli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1